# Showing $f$ is one-to-one using Jacobian

Tags: analysis

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ whose all partial derivatives are defined at every point. For all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $J(x)$ be the jacobian matrix of $f$ at $x$. If $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,|J(x)|>0$ then is $f$ locally one to one?

(It is known that this holds if we add that partial derivatives are continuous)

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/

Comment: @Moishe Cohen - It is even more than what I wanted! Thanks :)